# Question about Integration of Multiplication of Two functions

Tags: integration

If we have the following conditions

and $g(x)\geq 0,\; \forall x \in [0, x_0]$ and $f(x) < 0,\; \forall x \in [0, x_0]$ and $\int_{0}^{x_0}g(x)dx = 1$. How can I show that if it is?
\begin{equation}
\int_{0}^{x_0} f(x)g(x) dx < 0
\end{equation}

Comment: As stated this is false (as you could have $g(x)=0\;\forall x$.

Comment: Your question is unclear, please edit it so that the given and desired question are more clear !

Comment: I edited it to be more clear. What do you guys think?

Comment: Well this eliminates what @lulu said, since now $g(x)>0$ some $x\in[0,x_0]$. What do you know about the product $f(x)g(x)$ for all $x\in[0,x_0]$?

Comment: What I know is that $f(x) < 0$ and $g(x)\geq 0$ but it has a non zero measure. Is there a rigorous way to claim the integration I mentioned?

Comment: You know that $f(x)g(x)<0$ for all $x\in[0,x_0]$. Since the Riemann integral is just the infimum of the upper Riemann sums (or the supremum of the lower Riemann sums) over all partitions of the integration domain, and your function is strictly negative everywhere, the result follows.

Comment: Is it appropriate to write down that $f(x)g(x) \leq 0$ as $g(x) \geq 0$? The same arguments apply, no?

Comment: Edit to my previous comment: indeed you have $f(x)g(x)\le0$ for all $x\in[0,x_0]$, but since $g(x)\neq0$ for all $x\in[0,x_0]$, the integral will be strictly negative. Does this answer your question?

Comment: Btw it is convenient to use the @ to notify whoever you are responding to.@AhmadElMoslimany

Comment: I got you, I think you answered the question ... Thanks @B.Pasternak

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know that $f(x)g(x)\le0$ for all $x\in[0,x_0]$, and $f(x)g(x)<0$ for at least some $x\in[0,x_0]$. Since the Riemann integral is just the infimum of the upper Riemann sums (or equivalently the supremum of the lower Riemann sums) over all partitions of the integration domain, and your integrand takes either negative values or the value zero, it follows that $\int_0^{x_0} f(x)g(x)<0$.